# Get a pointer to a dictionary value (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, pointers

I'd like get a pointer to a dictionary value but ***[since the values are floats and not objects(actually this is wrong I was dealing with np.arrays).]*** it doesn't seem possible. Is there a way to get pointers to ***[floats] (or values)*** (in a dictionary) in python 3.x?

```
W = parameters["W" + str(l)] #not a pointer. I want a pointer.
b = parameters["b" + str(l)] #not a pointer
W = W - a*grads["dW" + str(l)] #W[l]−α dW[l]
b = b - a*grads["db" + str(l)] #b[l]=b[l]−α db[l]
```

W and b do not pass their updates into the dictionary.

::Edit:: The reason I thought this might be possible is because slices are references and not copies of array values. I thought dictionaries might have something similar.

Comment: why  you need a pointer?

Comment: Numbers and strings are not mutable in python. You can’t “update” them.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers.

Comment: @chandresh I don't NEED a pointer, but W is much more readable than parameters["W" + str(l)] and I'd rather not have to save W back into the array at the end after updating it.

Comment: No, you can't do this unless you define your own float class or something. One way you could achieve this is obviously by saving the dictionary key and looking it up again later.

Comment: The Edit section suggests that premise of copies vs slices needs revisiting and why they would apply to dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer is "No, you can't have references to dictionary values especially if they are primitives". I simply accepted that values are returned and came up with the obvious solution.

```
W = parameters["W" + str(l)] #not a reference
b = parameters["b" + str(l)] #not a reference

W = W - a*grads["dW" + str(l)] 
b = b - a*grads["db" + str(l)] 

parameters["W" + str(l)] = W #save back into the dictionary
parameters["b" + str(l)] = b #save back into the dictionary
```

This solution (without using references) has a lot of extra lines of code, but has shorter lines and makes the math section more readable.